# center button after change display mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with centering a button after I set it to `display: block`.
I've got a table:

```
<table border="0" id="contacts" width="100%">
    <tr><td><div align="center"><button style="width:200px;">btn1</button></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div align="center"><button style="width:200px;">btn1</button></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Both buttons are centered in the table.  Now I switch the visibility with:

```
document.getElementById("contacts").style.display = "none";
```

The table and buttons are invisible. After I switch the visibility back with:

```
document.getElementById("contacts").style.display = "block";
```

The buttons are aligned to the left. How can I center the buttons again?

Comment: Just use the same display property instead of block.

Comment: Hi - just following up. You really need to consider my answer. I don't mean you should choose it as correct - I don't care about that. I mean that you should use the information. Seriously - did you watch the video tutorial on flexbox that I posted in my answer? If not, please watch it *(it's only 25 minutes - and no, i didn't create it but I wish I did...)*. Anyway, give it some thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `document.getElementById("contacts").style.display = "table";`

Answer (score 2):

First, do not use a table structure for formatting. Tables have their place, but using them as HTML scaffolding is so 1990. Instead, use DIVs with css.

Break your page up into several outer boxes, or containers. *(For this, you can use DIVs - you can use DIVs for just about all containers - or sections or other container elements depending on your need for extra SEO cred.)*

Within each outer container (div), you then subdivide into the type of layout you need (again, using divs). Then, within each sub-area, again use divs (or other container element) to do any further sub-divisions.

So, how to size / position all these things? Use CSS.

In css, there is a reason why the most important change from Bootstrap3 to Bootstrap4 is moving from floats to flexbox. Floats was the old way to position items; flexbox (and CSSGrid) are the new way. Flexbox is dead *easy*.

Flexbox requires two things:

1. A parent container *(e.g. DIV, section, aside, p, etc)*
2. One or more child elements *(e.g. div, p, img, etc)*

[Here is an excellent 5min video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc)

[Here is a great cheatsheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also give it a class "align-content-center" in this example

```
<table border="0" id="contacts" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="align-content-center">
        <button style="width:200px;">btn1</button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div  class="align-content-center">
        <button style="width:200px;">btn1</button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and then just style your div around the buttons

```
.align-content-center{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```